# Criar um Scroll que sobe e desce Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá! Fiz um *scroll* com *javascript*. Após clicar em um *botão* ele sobe e um outro ele desce. Mas não gostei de deixar 2. Gostaria de usar um único botão pra ir pro topo e outro pro *final*.

O Código:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#scroll").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    });
  
    
    $("#scroll").click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 2000);
      return false;
      });
      });
```

Comment: Quer fazer as duas ações com um botão só é isso ? O botão vai para o topo e depois para o final ?

Comment: Isso. Consegui aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teste assim:

```js
$(function () {
  let botao = $('button');
  
  botao.on('click', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 2000, function () {
        botao.html('Descer');
      });
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, 2000, function () {
        botao.html('Subir');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button
{
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button">Descer</button>

<!-- <br> só p/ criar a rolagem na página -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
```